# How do I automate selecting price range in testrigor

Tags: testing, input, automation, range, testrigor

How do I automate selecting price range in testrigor ? that is working with input of type range

drag "canvas1" with offset "0,0" into "canvas1" with offset "0,10"

Answer (score 0):

I believe dragging the element with offset it's the best way to do it. Could you inspect the element and share the html tree? Maybe I can figure out another way.